# What do we call a small room in a boutique or a department store where we can try on a clothing?

Tags: word-request

What do you call a small room in a boutique or a department store where we can **try on** a piece of clothing?

Comment: A changing-room.

Answer (score 6):

I add one more to Edwin's suggestion:

[fitting room](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fitting-room#google_vignette)

> the place in a shop where you can try clothes on to see if they fit

Comment: This appears to be the most common usage in the eastern US.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I'd say interchangeable with "changing room"

Comment: @AndyBonner - Yes, but 'fitting room' is more specific to the 'try it on for size' area; 'changing room' is more generic, and can also refer to 'Get out of street clothes and put on your gym clothes or sports uniform' for athletics, or '... and put on your costume before going out on stage' for theatrical performance, etc..

Answer (score -1):

**More technically correct**: Trial Room

**More generally used**: Changing Room

Comment: "More technically correct: Trial Room" Where on earth is this used? Add a source to back this up.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Laurel maybe it's used in Indian English? https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/coming-age-trial-room-jermina-menon The author of this piece in Linkedin is Indian.

Comment: In the US, the only time I've heard the usage 'trial room' is for a chamber within my employer's facility where disciplinary hearings are conducted, when that hearing is conducted structurally like a criminal trial, with the intent of dismissal from employment upon a finding against the employee. "Changing room" isn't unknown for what I normally hear as "Fitting Room"

Comment: (Generally speaking, the room in an actual government facility used for actual criminal trials is called a 'courtroom', though technically 'trial room' wouldn't be incorrect.)